# Replace all double quotes only in Nth Column

Tags: linux, awk, sed, replace

I have a file like this

```
abc|def||ghi|jklm||uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|nopqrst|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|nopq"rst|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|"nopqrst"|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|"nopq"rst"|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|"nopq"r"st"|uv||xyz
```

The 6th Column could be double quoted. I want to replace all the occurances of double quotes in this field with a backslash-double quote (\")

I wish my output to look like

```
abc|def||ghi|jklm||uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|nopqrst|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|nopq\"rst|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|"nopqrst"|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|"nopq\"rst"|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|"nopq\"r\"st"|uv||xyz
```

I have tried combinations of below, but ending short each time

```
sed -i 's/\"/\\\"/2' file.txt (this replaces only 2nd occurrence)
sed -i 's/\"/\\\"/2g' file.txt (this replaces only 2nd occurrence and all rest also)
```

My file will be having millions of rows; so I may need a sed or awk command only.
Please help.

Comment: Can you have data like `"abc` or `xyz"` in the 6th column? That is, only starting or ending quote is present.

Comment: Can you have `|`s in the 6th column, e..g. `"foo|bar"`? Can you have quotes in any other column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution in any version of `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} {
   c1 = substr($6, 1, 1)
   c2 = substr($6, length($6), 1)
   s = substr($6, 2, length($6)-2)
   gsub(/"/, "\\\"", s)
   $6 = c1 s c2
} 1' file

abc|def||ghi|jklm||uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|nopqrst|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|nopq\"rst|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|"nopqrst"|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|"nopq\"rst"|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|"nopq\"r\"st"|uv||xyz
```

Comment: Thank you Anubhava. This works perfect for my requirement.

Answer (score 4):

If this isn't all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output including cases that this doesn't work for:

```
$ sed 's/"/\\"/g; s/|\\"/|"/g; s/\\"|/"|/g' file
abc|def||ghi|jklm||uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|nopqrst|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|nopq\"rst|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|"nopqrst"|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|"nopq\"rst"|uv||xyz
abc|def||ghi|jklm|"nopq\"r\"st"|uv||xyz
```

The above will work in any sed.

Comment: Thank you Ed Morton. Your solution is more generic and not limited to only column#6. This will surely be useful for me for my future work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/[^|]*/\n&\n/6            # isolate the 6th field
        h                          # make a copy
        s/"/\\"/g                  # replace " by \"
        s/\\(")\n|\n\\(")/\1\n\2/g # repair start and end "s
        H                          # append amended line to copy
        g                          # get copies to current line
        s/\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*/\2\1/' file # swap fields
```

Surround the 6th field by newlines and make a copy in the hold space.

Replace all `"`'s by `\"`'s and remove the `\`'s at the start and end of the field if the field begins and ends in `"`'s

Append the amended line to the copy and replace the current line by the doubled line.

Using pattern matching replace copied line 6th field by the amended one.